# Why does Apache support PHP, Perl, Python... but not Servlets?

Tags: php, apache, tomcat, servlets, web

I read the wikipedia article about the Apache HTTP Server and found that it has support for PHP, Perl, Python etc.

> Apache supports a variety of features, many implemented as compiled modules which extend the core functionality. These can range from server-side programming language support to authentication schemes. Some common language interfaces support Perl, Python, Tcl, and PHP.

So why not extend the same to support JSP & Servlets?

Also, I don't understand the support for Perl, PHP out of the box either. How can the server do the compilation? Shouldn't the server receive fully compiled plain html documents to serve?

PS: I am not entirely sure I understand the difference between Tomcat & Apache

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two of several reasons:
- Because **Apache Tomcat** is servlet container. Servlets use Java (**compile programming langague**). PHP, Python, Perl run on **Apache HTTP Server**, they are **scripting programming languages**.
- The separation for small footprint install file and better performance.